# How to use Material-UI withMobileDialog HOC in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm having trouble using withMobileDialog in TypeScript.

Here's my code, based on the code sample [in the docs](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/#responsive-full-screen).

```js
import withMobileDialog, { InjectedProps } from "@material-ui/core/withMobileDialog";

class MyComponent extends React.Component<
  MyComponentProps & InjectedProps, MyComponentState> { 
    ... 
}

export default withMobileDialog()(MyComponent);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<InjectedProps & Partial<WithWidth>>'.
  Type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<InjectedProps & Partial<WithWidth>, any>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible. ts(2345)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the types of `@material-ui/core`. We also inject a `width` prop. The following code should pass:

```
import { WithWidth } from "@material-ui/core/withWidth";
import withMobileDialog, { InjectedProps } from "@material-ui/core/withMobileDialog";

class MyComponent extends React.Component<
  MyComponentProps & InjectedProps & Partial<WithWidth>, MyComponentState> { 
    ... 
}

export default withMobileDialog()(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried this and it doesn't work, I get the same error as in the question.

Comment: I would need to see the full example with the version you're using. It is working for me.